# What is the nma_deice_log_size_bytes error?

Tags: ios, here-api

I notice in my crashlytics by FireBase and my BugSnag reports, that the app is crashing due to `nma_deice_log_size_bytes` errors coming from the NMAKit.

I can't find any documentation on the issue, or how to resolve it. It provides no stack trace, or anyway to figure out what is causing this issue. What is this error, and how does one go about fixing it?

The only other information that is given, is 
`Crashed: com.here.maps.eventqueue
EXC_BAD_ACCESS KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS 0x0000000000000000`
 from the Crashlytics report and

`Attempted to dereference null pointer` on the BugSnag report.

Comment: Can you please help to know the version of  SDK ?

Comment: @HEREDeveloperSupport We are currently running 3.12

Answer (score 0):

The nma_deice_log_size_bytes is just a method of HERE SDK, it doesn't have anything custom.Crash is caused by memory access (access to pointer, that became NULL). The reason why it became NULL might be memory corruption.

We would require more information regarding that application scenario that causes crash. The best options would be to have steps to reproduce and short sample code that reproduces the issue. Could you please share the same.